# How do I set the max and min of the x-axis of Vega-Lite time series chart?

Tags: vega-lite

I'm making time series charts with Vega-Lite and I want to set the min and max values of the x-axis independent of the values that are being displayed. The reason is that I'm displaying multiple time series side by side in separate charts, and I want their x-axes to line up even when some series begin earlier than others.

I've found [`encoding.x.scale.domain`](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#domain), which seems like it's the right property to use. [The documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#domain) says that for temporal fields this should be a two element array of timestamps. However, it does not seem to matter what I set it to, my chart does not render any line, nor any ticks on the x-axis, and the warning `Infinite extent for field "data": [Infinity, -Infinity]"` is printed in the console.

Even more confusing is that I've been able to control the y-axis by setting `encoding.y.scale.domain` in the same way.

The following is a simplified version of the chart spec that I have experimented with in the Vega Editor. I'm trying to set the x-axis to start at an earlier point in time and end at a later point in time than the actual values:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"ts": 1500400000000, "v": 1},
      {"ts": 1500500000000, "v": 2},
      {"ts": 1500600000000, "v": 3},
      {"ts": 1500700000000, "v": 2}
    ]
  },
  "width": 800,
  "height": 300,
  "mark": {"type": "line"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "ts", "type": "temporal", "scale": {"domain": [1500000000000, 1500900000000]}},
    "y": {"field": "v", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"domain": [0, 5]}}
  }
}
```

If I remove the `encoding.x.scale.domain` property it renders a line, but when including it I can't figure out any values that don't result in the warning.

Is this even the right way to set the min and max of the x-axis? Why does it work for the y-axis but not x-axis? What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you tried is the correct way to specify temporal domains in Vega-Lite, but there is a bug in this behavior that was introduced in Vega-Lite 4.5. Here is the result of your spec using Vega-Lite 4.4:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega@5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-lite@4.4"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-embed@6"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
  <script>
      var spec = {
        "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
        "data": {
          "values": [
            {"ts": 1500400000000, "v": 1},
            {"ts": 1500500000000, "v": 2},
            {"ts": 1500600000000, "v": 3},
            {"ts": 1500700000000, "v": 2}
          ]
        },
        "width": 800,
        "height": 300,
        "mark": {"type": "line"},
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "ts", "type": "temporal", "scale": {"domain": [1500000000000, 1500900000000]}},
          "y": {"field": "v", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"domain": [0, 5]}}
        }
      };
      vegaEmbed("#vis", spec);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I've filed a bug report at https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/6060

Comment: Thank you. The issue has already been fixed too, that's great.